# add up array element 3 by 3

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently learning java arrays. Is there any way I can loop through an array of size 9
and do the following

```
sum1 = array[0] + array[1] + array[2] 
sum2 = array[3] + array[4] + array[5]
sum3 = array[6] + array[7] + array[8]
```

I tried but I could not achieve my desired output.

```
public class Sum {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            // if it's divisible by 3, reset the sum to 0
            if (i > 1 && i % 3 == 0) {
                sum = 0;
            }
            else {
                sum += array[i];
                System.out.println(sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not far from a solution, but really, you should figure that out by yourself. Execute the algorithm on paper, and, at each iteration, ask yourself what you should do.

Comment: Sure, that's `array[3*i]+array[3*i+1]+array[3*i+2]`.

Comment: at least give some hints on which part is wrong?

Comment: If you want the sums to be in 3 different variables, I'd just make an `int[]` and store them in that at indices `0, 1, 2` during execution of the loop. Obviously you need an array that has a size that can have values at those indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    sum += array[i];
    if (i > 0 && (i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.println(sum);
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting the sum to 0 ok, but then not adding the number that you've reset it on (because of your else condition.)

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop by increasing by 3, knowing that the length of the array is a multiple of 3.

```
public class Sum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i+=3) {      // increase i by 3
            sum += array[i] + array[i+1] + array[i+2];
            System.out.println(sum);
            sum=0;
        }
    } 

}
```